# Accessed App Maker Site, but displayed 404 error

Tags: google-app-maker

I accessed "https://appmaker.google.com/?hl=ja" App Maker Site, but displayed 404 error.
Please let me know how to access App Maker Site.

Answer (score 1):

appmaker was discontinued. it is no longer a product offered as part of gsuite.